# Is there a way to obtain US and UK customs data?

Tags: data-request, usa, uk, migration

I'm being asked to find all the information I can about US and UK customs data, but I just don't know where to search for, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could submit a Freedom of Information Act Request to CBP. Here's a [link](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia) with more information on how to do that.

The UK has a similar law. Here is a [link](https://www.gov.uk/make-a-freedom-of-information-request) to the non-specific FOI instructions for the UK. And a [specific link for HM Revenue and Customs](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs).

Comment: Just one question, do you know if i have to be an us citizen to apply for this act?

Comment: I know for the US you are not required to be a citizen. Foreign entities make requests all the time. I am not familiar with the UK laws though.